# Telerik UI ASP.NET MVC - issues with chart rendering

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a bar chart which is rendered via the Telerik MVC wrapper.
I am trying to increase the `height` of the chart, and have the chart fill out the entire area. This is where I'm having trouble.

Resizing the `width` seems to work just fine out of the box (as far as I can see there's no additional javascript code to handle this).

Here's the chart:

[image]

and the chart definition in my `cshtml` page:

```html
@* Comparison chart *@
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("window")
.Title("Comparison")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "chart-window " + guid })
.Visible(false)
.Draggable()
.Resizable()
.Width(700)
.Height(600)
.Actions(actions => actions.Maximize().Close())
.Content(@<text>
<div class="chart-wrapper">
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
 .Name("chart")
 .Theme("Material")
 //.Title("Comparison Chart")
 .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top))
 .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("transparent"))
 .Series(series =>
 {
  series.Bar(Model.Where(m => !m.SubTitle.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(m => (double)m.Utilisation))
   .Name(Settings.Whatif.SummaryCurrentExposureName)
   .Color("#5cb85c")
   .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Format("{0:,0}"))
   .Spacing(0)
   .Gap(2);

  if (Model.Any(a => a.WhatIfRun))
  {
   series.Bar(Model.Where(m => !m.SubTitle.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(m => (double)m.WhatifExposure))
    .Name("What-if")
    .Color("#222222")
    .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Format("{0:,0}"));
  }

 })
 .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
  .Name("label-axis")
  .Categories(Model.Where(m => !m.SubTitle.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(m => m.Title + "\n" + m.SubTitle)) 

 )
 .ValueAxis(axis => axis
  .Numeric()
  .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:,0}").Rotation(-90))
  .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
  .AxisCrossingValue(0, int.MinValue)
 )
 .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
  .Visible(true)
  .Format("{0:,0}")
  .Template("#= series.name #: #= kendo.toString(value, 'n0') #")
 )
)
</div>
</text>)
)
```

I've tried to capture the `resize` event in JavaScript, but it doesn't hit this event:

```
   $(".chart-wrapper").resize(function ()
{
    alert("RESIZED !!!");
});
```

Any help is appreciated. In the meantime, I will keep researching...

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using the `.ChartArea()` property for the height is what works.

So the line which causes the chart to fully render to the height specified is:

```
.ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("transparent").Height(600))
```

[image]